# Using a named range to create dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

What I've read on similar topics is the opposite of what I want to do. So I am asking to see if it's even possible.

Currently I have a sheet that uses the following sub to create a drop down list based on a comma delimited string of names

```
    Sub MakeList(ByRef r As Range, ByRef Config As String)

    r.Clear
    If Not Config = "" Then
        r.Select
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Config
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
    End If
    End Sub
```

In a different application, I would like to take a range I have already named within the workbook and apply it to this. That way the drop down box would expand when someone adds a cell to the named range. I've seen some posts about dynamic ranges and how to name a range within vba, but both look ugly and code intensive.

Comment: That code should happily work if you give it `=NameOfYourNamedRage` for a `Config` parameter. Have you tried it?

Comment: How would I do that with config being a string? Is there a certain way I need to initialize it first?

Comment: Well you pass `"=NameOfTheRange"` as an argument. Excel understands the list as a source, there's no need to comma-separate the individual values.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you @Mathieu Guindon! I didn't realize excel was able to do that but it's exactly what I need and much simpler without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Mathieu Guindon for the solution. The answer was very simple but I did not know the extent of excels ability.

Instead of looping through `Range("NameOfRange")` and taking the value of each cell, you can call the sub `MakeList` with `"=NameOfRange"` as the String argument. Excel will automatically populate the list with the values within your named range.

---

Edit:

For anyone that comes across this, the named range must be a continuous range in a single column or row. Essentially all conditions apply as if you were to do the dropdown list manually within the sheet. If your named range doesn't meet this condition, you will have to loop through and store the values in a comma delimited string and run it through the code above. Otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Table/Named Range combination is pretty simple.  Just put your source data in a table (ctrl+t), then select the column of data and assign it a name.  Then set your list source for your data validation to the new named range.
Here's a quick tutorial that shows you how to do it:
https://www.excelcampus.com/tips/dynamic-data-validation/

Comment: This isn't the application I'm looking for. This does it all within the worksheet and validates the whole column as only the values in the named range.

What I'm trying to do is have a named range on one sheet, then when my code validates the list on another sheet it can pull the named range rather than my code re-initializing it. If my question isn't clear I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @CRunyon yet if you actually read the article to step 3, you'll see that all you need to do is to use your named range's `Name` (preceded by an `=` operator) for the `Formula1` argument when you add the data validation.

Comment: CRunyon, the example I gave is not dependent on the validation data being on the same sheet.  That's the beauty of using the named range - it allows the data to reside pretty much anywhere.  Also, by using a Table to store the validation values, you're not using the entire sheet column, just the Table column.